# React-Redux connect issues in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am a trying to make a component which gets passed to react-redux's `connect` function.
The component is as follows:

```
interface ITestProps {
  id: number
}

class TestComponent extends React.Component<ITestProps, {}> {
  render() {
    return (<div>
      {this.props.name}
    </div>)
  }
}

mapStateToProps(state) {}
mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {}

let ConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TestComponent)
```

The above code seems to work find if i render `ConnectedComponent` like so

```
<ConnectedComponent></ConnectedComponent>
```

i.e without the `id` prop. Shouldn't it throw an error since the `ConnectedComponent` is simply the connected form of `TestComponent` and `TestComponent` should have props of the form `ITestProps`.
Is this how it is supposed to behave or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Not familiar with TypeScript, but why do you need a different name (ConnectedComponent)? Can you not just do something like `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TestComponent);` and then `< TestComponent ></TestComponent >`?

Comment: That is how I do.. I just thought this way it would be easier to understand

Comment: Hello, which definition types are you using for redux-react ?

Comment: The ones from **DefinitelyTyped**  . This is my `typings.json` entry
```"react-redux": "registry:dt/react-redux#4.4.0+20160501125835"```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure why the typings can't infer the type from the presentational component alone, but it will work if ownProps is typed in connect ->

```
let ConnectedComponent = connect<{}, {}, ITestProps>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TestComponent)
```

It also can infer it if ownProps is typed in mapDispatchToProps ->

```
mapStateToProps(state, ownProps: ITestProps) {}
```

Comment: by adding second argument to mapStateToProps (state) vs (state, ownProps) you're removing a lot of optimizations from connect! yes, react-redux does detect how many arguments you used in your function (mapStateToProps.length) and applies different optimization strategy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what sort of optimizations get removed?

Answer (score 1):

Include a constructor inside the class like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
}
```

Without the constructor the props don't get loaded

Instead of

```
let ConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TestComponent)
```

I added (obviously `mapStateToProps` & `mapDispatchToProps` have to be defined before the connect function)

```
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

above

```
class TestComponent extends React.Component<ITestProps, {}> {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour. connect() will return a new container component that wraps your TestComponent as a child.

Here's part of the source code

```
class Connect extends Component {
...
    render() {
        const selector = this.selector
        selector.shouldComponentUpdate = false

        if (selector.error) {
          throw selector.error
        } else {
          return createElement(WrappedComponent, 
              this.addExtraProps(selector.props))
        }
    }
...
}
```

But you can specify the interface of the container's props as said by Radio- (and also the interfaces of StateProps and DispatchProps).
You can see from the type definition that accepts TStateProps, TDispatchProps and TOwnProps, and will return ComponentDecorator

```
export declare function connect<TStateProps, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>(
    mapStateToProps?: MapStateToProps<TStateProps, TOwnProps> | MapStateToPropsFactory<TStateProps, TOwnProps>,
    mapDispatchToProps?: MapDispatchToProps<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps> | MapDispatchToPropsFactory<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
    mergeProps?: MergeProps<TStateProps, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
    options?: Options
): ComponentDecorator<TStateProps & TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;
```