# How to resolve typescript error TS2339: Property 'XXX' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ...?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my typescript/reactjs app I am trying to pass in a property called test like this, this is part of the index.tsx:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={getStore()}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App test={1} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

In my app.tsx I have:

```
export class App extends React.Component<any,{}>{
  constructor(props){
    super(props); 
  }

  render(){
    ..
  }
}
```

When I run the app I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
(24,12): error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<{}, ComponentState>> & Readonly<{ childr...'.
```

How can I make sure this error is resolved or how can I pass in a property on my App component?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a larger issue with ReactRedux connect, and Typescript, there has been such a problem finding a workable solution, that our team is seriously considering dropping Typescript in our react apps because of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an `interface` for your component's `Props` and pass that as a type argument to `React.Component`. This way, `App` will expect to receive a `prop` called `test`. For example:

```
interface Props {
    test: <whatever type test is>
}

class App extends React.Component<Props, {}> {

    // your component code
}
```

There is some notorious discussion around `connect` with TS. You may check out this SO post for help: [Typescript + React/Redux: Property "XXX" does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657792/typescript-react-redux-property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsicattrib?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the component name starts with capital letter