# typescript typing connect props for class component [duplicated]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

duplicating this question: [Typescript + React/Redux: Property "XXX" does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657792/typescript-react-redux-property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsicattrib)
But with a better minimal snippet and reference.

### question

When using `react-redux`+`typescript`, I found that the `props` mapped by `connect` is not recognized by `tslint`.

Error and example as below:

> Property 'counter' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)

> Property 'counterAdd' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)

Here's part of the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-question-9si7t)(same as (#what I did, first line):

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>{this.props.counter}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.props.counterAdd}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state: any) => ({
    counter: state.counter
  }),
  {
    counterAdd: () => ({ type: "ADD" })
  }
)(App);
```

### What I did

- Tried searching for a while and made [a minimal snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-question-9si7t).
- Found a [documentation on functional component](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component)

Answer (score 0):

Assign the [Generic Type Variables](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) like this

```
- class App extends React.Component {
```

```js
+ class App extends React.Component<{
+   counter: number;
+   counterAdd: () => object;
+ }> {
```

[Check the effect](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-question-answered-lpih4)