# React-Redux connect missing in type IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes

Tags: c#, react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0

There's a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243652/react-redux-connect-issues-in-typescript), but the solution doesn't fix my issue.

I created a Asp.net core project using "React & Redux" template. And created a react component like below:

```
export interface SessionProp {
    user?: string
}

type SessionContainerProp =
    SessionProp &
    typeof SessionStore.actionCreators;

export class SessionContainer extends React.Component<SessionContainerProp, {}> {
    constructor(props: SessionContainerProp) {
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //check if user loged in
        this.props.reqestCurrentUser()
    }

    public render() {
        if (this.props.user != null) {
            return <Layout />;
        }
        else {
            return <Login />;
        }
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.session, 
    SessionStore.actionCreators                
)(SessionContainer) as typeof SessionContainer;
```

The *sessionStore.actionCreators* like below:

```
export const actionCreators = {
    reqestCurrentUser: () => {        
        return <CheckUserLoginAction>{ type: Actions.CheckUserLogin, user: 'a' };
    }
};
```

IMO, there should be no issue if I render the component without any props like `<SessionContainer />`. However, the VS Code raise error as below:

> Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNod...'.
>     Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.
>       Property 'reqestCurrentUser' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; }'.

What am I missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fix the issue by replace the

```
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.session, 
    SessionStore.actionCreators                
)(SessionContainer) as typeof SessionContainer;
```

with

```
export const SessionWrapContainer = connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.session, 
    SessionStore.actionCreators                
)(SessionContainer);
```

I still don't figure out why this solution works, but it does solve my problem.